# Leveraging and optimizing SIMD for matrix axis looping in cython

Tags: cython, simd, avx, auto-vectorization

The following cython 3.0.8 code is being compiled and run on a machine with AVX2 support with the -O3 compilation flag, but does not seem to make any use of SIMD instructions when used from the below python main.

```
import numpy as np
from libc.math cimport fabs

cpdef inline double[:,:] go(double[:] stream, double[:] query):
      
    matrix = np.empty((len(stream), len(query)))
    cdef double [:, :] matrix_c = matrix
   
    cdef int i, j
    cdef int stream_len = len(stream)
    for i in range(stream_len):
        for j in range(len(query)):
            matrix_c[i, j] = fabs(stream[i] - query[j])

    return matrix
```

Running the python main with the `perf` command there are less than 10 calls to SIMD instructions when `i` and `j` range over 100,000 and 20 respectively:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
import go

if __name__ == '__main__':
    np.random.seed(42)
    stream = np.random.rand(100000)
    query = np.linspace(0, 1, 20)
    print(f'mean runtime is {np.mean(timeit.repeat(lambda: go(stream, query), number=10, repeat=100))}')
```

Would you have any suggestions for how to modify it in order to allow the underlying compiler (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc) to leverage SIMD vector operations?

For checking if SIMD is being used I am using the following command, though I'd gladly use a differnt method if you recommend one:

```
 perf stat -e instructions:u,fp_arith_inst_retired.128b_packed_single:u,fp_arith_inst_retired.256b_packed_single:u,fp_arith_inst_retired.128b_packed_double:u,fp_arith_inst_retired.256b_packed_double:u -- python -m main.py
```

Indeed perf shows 1.5 million uses of SIMD ...

---

This is cython 3.0.x, so some of the syntax may possibly look new to some people. I'm compiling and running on Ubuntu, it's my first time with cython as well as with looking to explicitly coerce the use of  SIMD. Trying out `-march=native` makes no difference.

---

I'm attaching the gcc invocations made during the cython build:

> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/.venv3.10/include -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c ....c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/....o -O3 -march=native

> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -g -fwrapv -O2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/....o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/....cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -O3 -march=native

---

using the `-fopt-info` flag does yield 24 instances of loops being vectorized in the now much much longer build output (thousands of lines) however they relate to lines of code which I'm hard to associate to my own code's logic, such as lines of code where cython handles its memory views. Output lines such as:

> main.c:14454:3: optimized: loop vectorized using 32 byte vectors

I guess that had I written this in C myself, I could have associated the optimization messages to my code quite more directly.

## Update

Double vectorization is already taking place:
[image]

So it only remains to see if the code can be optimized further, which is slightly easier to do in pure C rather than through a generated C source of dozens of thousands of lines of code from cython :-)

Comment: Your input data is `double`-precision FP, so if it vectorized you'd expect counts for `fp_arith_inst_retired.128b_packed_double:u` (and/or 256b if you also compiled with `-march=native` or something that includes AVX, like `-march=x86-64-v3`).  For AVX/AVX2, you can also check the disassembly for any use of `YMM` registers.  For XMM, you also have to rule out `subsd` (Scalar Double) vs. `subpd` (Packed Double).

Comment: See also [How to check if compiled code uses SSE and AVX instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47878352) - one of the answers also mentions GCC's `-fopt-info` to report on which loops were or weren't auto-vectorized.  You might need to enable `-ffast-math` or perhaps just `-fno-math-errno` for `fabs` - no "unsafe" optimizations are *needed* to vectorize this, but GCC is sometimes held back by otherwise-trivial math library functions and its default of having them set errno, and/or by its bad default of trapping math: use `-fno-trapping-math`.

Comment: Thanks, `-fopt-info` was certainly something I was looking for. (While perf also makes sense in seeing whether the amount of times these instructions have been used is seemingly proportional to the input size). The thousands of lines long output from `-fopt-info` does mention vectorization 24 times, so I'll dwell on analyzing it further.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/YGf1chroM shows a C version of your function (taking a pointer to an output matrix, not allocating new space).  GCC and Clang auto-vectorize it even without `-ffast-math` or any similar options, to an inner loop of `vsubpd  ymm0, ymm2, [rcx+rsi]` to subtract query[j] from a loop-invariant / `vandpd  ymm0, ymm0, ymm3` for `fabs` / `vmovupd [rax+rsi], ymm0` to store the result.

Comment: Well thanks a lot @PeterCordes, it seems that I do get 1.5 million uses of fp_arith_inst_retired.256b_packed_double (I should have noticed earlier). Even without any of the added flags, some of which sure point out more things I need to learn about. So I think I have enough to chew on now. The Internet is no longer broken, in terms of the profile :-) I'll post some kind of an answer after some more careful observation.

Comment: As I understand from your helpful comments, GCC is smart enough to infer how to vectorize computations involving many math functions from the standard library, not just arithmetics, which actually makes a lot of sense.

Comment: That's correct; unless you use `-fno-builtin-fabs` for example, it treats it as a builtin function.  It can do constant folding through it, like `fabs(-0.5)` being a constant `0.5`, and knows that `fabs(x-y) = fabs(y-x)` (which I think is true for floating point; `-0.0` isn't a problem since fabs also produces `+0.0`.)  It also means it can vectorize it.  Some basic math operations like `sqrt` and absolute value have functions, some have operators like `-`, but it's important for an optimizing compiler to be able to inline those very simple functions.

Comment: Thank you, I have learned so much from this. Now I can optimize further by blocking according to cache size, and by making sure that the numpy array layouts are simple enough to avoid cython's thousands of lines of code having to do superfluous things when handling them.

Answer (score 1):

Well, SIMD is being used after all, I was just negligent in choosing which instructions to let the perf command monitor. Since my code uses doubles, the following is the appropriate perf command to demonstrate the amount of SIMD going on over doubles:

```
 perf stat -e instructions:u,fp_arith_inst_retired.128b_packed_double:u,fp_arith_inst_retired.256b_packed_double:u -- python -m main.py
```

Which yields something like:

[image]

The previously included `*_single` AVX instructions are superfluous to monitor in this specific case, but may come in handy in other cases (when non-double float types are involved).

So the 100,000 outer loops of this cython code, ~1.5 million SIMD instructions operating on doubles on a 256 bits register are taking place.

The inner loop ranges over 20 subtractions of doubles, which after packing the numbers into the SIMD register can take just 5 cpu cycles (4 doubles packed on the 256 bit register) per inner loop execution. This makes sense.

I can't rule out that this can be further optimized (on a single core) through better cython or in ways that make cython jump through less hoops going around the numpy array inputs. Writing this directly in C ― while generating a numpy array to return through numpy's C api ― should potentially be faster to optimize, hopefully without scarificing safety.

Thank you @PeterCordes for all your help on this.

Comment: Some modern CPUs like Ice Lake can do 2 stores per clock cycle, so could average better than 1 vector per cycle.  (FP Subtract + bitwise and (fabs) costs 2 vector uops, and Intel P-cores "only" have three vector ALU execution ports, two of which can do FP add/sub/mul/FMA, so 1.5 vectors per clock cycle average, unless the front-end is a bottleneck (5 uops per clock on ICL, 6 on Alder Lake)).  https://travisdowns.github.io/blog/2019/06/11/speed-limits.html / https://uops.info/. Zen 1-4 can sustain at best 1 vector store per clock, although Zen 3 and later can do 2 scalar integer stores / clock.

Comment: I hope this loop is a pretty small part of your whole program, since 1.5 M out of 40.1 billion instructions being SIMD is a pretty tiny part of the whole program's workload (and total run time.)  But yeah, as long as that number scales the way you expect with your problem size, it confirms your loop vectorized.  Note that `vandpd` (to implement `fabs`) is not an `fp_arith` instruction, it's just bitwise boolean.  `fp_arith` counters count FLOPS (including counting 2 for an FMA, despite their names), and only count true FP math that cares about rounding modes and so on.

Comment: Yes indeed, it's a very small part of my computational graph and a total case of overly-local optimization, which I regard as a stepping stone to getting into minimally viable shape for going on to optimize at large. It's nice if I could perf only one function without all the slow python calling and timing it, and as I doubt that's an option I'll time the complement to get that number (i.e. run the slow python wrapper with a mostly empty cpdef in place of the real one, even then, generating the input arrays, this process takes multiple runs with different ablations, but doable).

Comment: There are multiple ways to do that: [`perf_event_open` with some helper libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27749804), [fork/exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26267588/perf-stat-for-part-of-program) `perf stat -p $PID` and kill it, or in more recent `perf`, write start/stop commands into the control pipe it can open ([Enable/disable perf event collection programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70314376)).  Or for the purpose of this question, make a simple test caller that just generates 2 random arrays and calls it without doing the rest of your computations.